# Need to reload bash every time i open terminal?

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, osx-lion

Every time I open terminal, I don't seem to have my bash profile loaded.
By this, I mean if I type:

git
node
brew

etc... i get "command not found"

If I run:

> source ~/.bashrc

Then it fixes the issue.
I seem to have to do this on each restart

Any way to make it do this automatically?

Comment: have you tried putting source ~/.bashrc into .bash_profile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

in `~/.profile` or `~/.bash_profile`

Answer (score 3):

Presumably this is Mac OS X, right? The reason you see this behaviour is that Terminal.app creates a login shell, which only sources `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.profile` if the former doesn't exist. To solve your problem, either:

- Source your `~/.bashrc` from your `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.profile`
- Put your commands in `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.profile` instead of `~/.bashrc`
- Configure Terminal.app to create a interactive non-login shell.

Comment: "Configure Terminal.app to create a non-login shell." Don't you mean "an interactive shell" (see "Invocation" section of `man bash`)?

Comment: To be precise, a "interactive non-login" shell.

Comment: in profile I have: alias es2="ember server -p 4202“ but when running es2 it only puts **ember** to the console